# WebSphere Application Server, IIS Web Server - Propogation of web server plugin to WebServer nodes when application is redeployed

Tags: iis, websphere

My question is if 'propogation' of web plugin's xml file to Web Server nodes is necessary when an application is re-deployed in Websphere.

We have webservers infront of our application servers. During environment setup, our Web Admin manually generated web server plugin xml(from WAS console) and copied to web server nodes to establish communication between IIS and WebSphere. But it was a one-time job and we do not care about replacing it on web servers anymore when we redeploy the application for our releases.(And there is no way that plugin xml is automatically copied over as our web server configuration does not reflect actual web server nodes!)

It would be great to hear about standard practice, and how rest of you are doing it.

Any inputs are greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is not required, nor I'd say recommended in the prod environment, to avoid accidental changes of the plugin-cfg. So if new plugin is needed you may generate it and manually apply required changes to the prod version of the config.

Comment: That helps. Thank you Gas!